# Duda en claves foraneas mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Saludos amigos tengo la siguiente duda, consiste en un pequeño proyecto donde me planteo lo siguiente:

- Un proceso posee uno o varios procedimientos y a su vez este procedimiento puede pertenecer a uno o varios procesos.
- Una norma posee una o varias clausulas
- Una auditoria posee una o varias clausulas de distintas normas(1 o
  mas)
  Para lo cual ya me planteo el siguiente diseño:
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi Sql:

```
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- jue 21 feb 2019 19:57:42 -05
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`proceso`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`proceso` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(200) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`procedimiento`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`procedimiento` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(200) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`proceso_has_procedimiento`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`proceso_has_procedimiento` (
  `proceso_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `procedimiento_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_proceso_has_procedimiento_procedimiento1_idx` (`procedimiento_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_proceso_has_procedimiento_proceso_idx` (`proceso_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_proceso_has_procedimiento_proceso`
    FOREIGN KEY (`proceso_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`proceso` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_proceso_has_procedimiento_procedimiento1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`procedimiento_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`procedimiento` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`norma`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`norma` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`clausula`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`clausula` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `norma_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_clausula_norma1_idx` (`norma_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_clausula_norma1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`norma_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`norma` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`detalle_auditoria`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`detalle_auditoria` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `clausula_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `proceso_has_procedimiento_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_detalle_auditoria_clausula1_idx` (`clausula_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_detalle_auditoria_proceso_has_procedimiento1_idx` (`proceso_has_procedimiento_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_detalle_auditoria_clausula1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`clausula_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`clausula` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_detalle_auditoria_proceso_has_procedimiento1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`proceso_has_procedimiento_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`proceso_has_procedimiento` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`auditoria`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`auditoria` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `numero` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `fecha_inicio` DATE NULL,
  `lugar` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `detalle_auditoria_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_auditoria_detalle_auditoria1_idx` (`detalle_auditoria_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_auditoria_detalle_auditoria1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`detalle_auditoria_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`detalle_auditoria` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Ahora mi duda es si esta bien relacionado o no dado que una auditoria puede tener distintas clausulas de distintas normas, agradeceria cualquier sugerencia..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues, Diego, me temo que no. A partir de la semántica que describes yo llego a un modelo ER como el que te adjunto. Y, además, me surgen un par de dudas:

- ¿Qué relación existe entre procedimientos, procesos y auditorías? En tu semántica no lo comentas pero, en el SQL, sí que vinculas cada auditoría a cada relación entre proceso y procedimiento. Supongo que algo tendrán que ver, como que se auditen los procedimientos que se abren para los procesos o algo similar.
- ¿Cada norma tiene sus propias cláusulas o hay cláusulas que pueden estar compartidas por varias normas? Simplemente para confirmar esa cardinalidad que he puesto.

Una corrección que sí que puedes realizar desde ya mismo es mover el campo detalle_auditoria_id desde auditoria a la otra tabla detalle_auditoria, ahí donde lo tienes no está teniendo el efecto que esperas. Tal vez con ese cambio ya soluciones el problema sin tener en cuenta todo lo anterior.

Y una última cosa: si utilizas nombres para las entidades y verbos para las relaciones, se entiende mucho mejor la motivación de cada tabla.

Espero haber podido ayudarte.

[image: Modelo ER de la semántica propuesta]